# Facebook API and escaping of quotes

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

when working with facebook api there is a problem when you post on the wall if you come across a quote, single or double in the post then appears with a slash, for example your's becomes like your\'s.

```
$response = $fb->post("/{$group_id}/photos", array(
  'message' => $text,
  'url' => $image,
  'published' => false,
  'scheduled_publish_time' => $time
 ), $token);
```

I try "Don\'t" , "Don\\'t" , 'Don\'t' but nothing helps

Comment: No, there is no such problem with the API. The issue is likely with your code - have you made a debug output of what $text contains?

Comment: indeed, as I had not thought of, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must not escape the string for the Facebook Graph API.
For example if you escaped your string with real_escape_sting() and stored the string in a database you can undo the effect with this command:

`$fbtext = stripslashes(str_replace("\\r\\n", "\n", $row->fbtext));`

This changes the \r\n to a newline and removes all other backslashes.
This is working great unless you need a backslash in your text.
In case you need backslashes in your text i would work with preg_replace.